# Is it possible to programmatically force an ios ap in split view to go full screen in ios9?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios9, splitview

I am developing this app for ipad and ios9 and at some point the user will click on a button to watch a video. But I wouldn't want the user to just see it in the split view size he's currently on (like 1/3rd or 14th) instead I would like the app to close the other open app and for it to take over the entire screen.

Does anyone know if that's possible? Thanks.

Comment: by-default video will go full screen...

Comment: Do you have a link to a test app by any chance? And what happens once the video stops playing? Does it go back to the split view or will the app be full screen then?

Comment: link to test app? there are no such things... when video stops, it will go to the screen where your were (split view). Its just like video get started in full screen and once finished it gets dismissed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By-default, the video always get played in full-screen mode. When video playing is finished, the player gets dismissed and you will see your screen (from where you played the video). In your case, in split view controller.

Do let me know if you need further details.